# An argument in Galois Theory notes about which i have no idea

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, separable-extension

I am self studying Galois theory through lecture notes but I am not able to find a reason why an argument should hold.

Please help.

Argument is - Let $K$ be a field and $f(x)$ belonging to $K[x]$ be irreducible, separable polynomial of degree $3$.Then if Galois group of $f$ is $S_3$ , then there are $4$ proper intermediate fields, $K(\delta)$ , $K(a)$ , $K(b)$ , $K(c)$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are roots of $f$ and $\delta$ is discriminant raised to power $\frac{1}{2}$

Can someone please tell why there must be $4$ intermediate fields.

Comment: What are the subgroups of $S_3$?

Comment: @rae 306 yes, I was a bit busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

The Galois correspondence provides a one-to-one correspondence between the intermediate fields of $L/K$ and the subgroups of $S_3$.

From group theory, we know that $S_3=\{(),(12),(13),(23),(123),(132) \}$ contains three subgroups of order $2$ (= index 3) (the transpositions $(12),(13)$ and $(23)$) and one subgroup of order 3 (= index 2), which is $A_3$.

It is well-known (see also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625101/need-help-in-proving-a-corollary-in-galois-theory-related-to-galois-group-of-pol/3625135#3625135)) that the intermediate field corresponding to $A_3$ is generated by $\sqrt{\Delta}$, where $\Delta$ is the discriminant. Then the other three subgroups are then exactly the ones generated by a root of $f$, since $f$ is irreducible.